# css block height

Tags: html, css

Block element, inside another block. First block is 200px height, so inner block should get total margins + padding + border + height of 200px according to the CSS specification. So in google chrome web developer tools, margins top and bottom are only 16 px, and total height + padding + margins is like 134. Any explanations, please?

```
 <html>
 <div style="height: 200px;border:1px solid black;">
 <p style="height: 50%; border:1px solid black;"></p>
 </div>
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: [This looks fine](http://jsfiddle.net/aLEhg/) in Chrome 25.0.1362.0 canary, FF 18 and Safari 6.0, to me.

Comment: where are the margins adding up to 200px. please read the question before voting down.

Comment: I didn't vote up or down. _I did read your question._ Please don't assume someone who leaves a comment that is intended to be helpful down-voted it. My remark was meant to solicit further details, which it did: Thinking the margins are supposed to add up to 200px, as you scornfully noted in your reply, is a relevant detail that was not explicitly stated in your question or suggested by the markup you provided which didn't have any margins set, at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property). The `200px` is by default the *content-box* which does not include `padding` or `border`. So the math for the `p` is `50%` of `200px` = `100px` content-box height, then add `1px` border twice plus `16px` margin twice (based off what you state it is), gives a value of `134px`.